# Trying to delete a saved Excel file but getting the IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: .net, excel, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to read an Excel file, view it on a table and then save the data into a database. However, whenever I try importing the same file again I keep getting the IOException. I am almost sure the process that is accessing the file is my own program. 
What am I missing and what should I do?

I was trying to closing the file as it may still be open, however was not so sure about how that should be done.

Here is where I get the exception:

```
 if(excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
            {

                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelfile.FileName);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) System.IO.File.Delete(path);

                excelfile.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: You are deleting the file and then again saving it ?

Comment: Yeah, in case someone edits the file and saves it using the same name

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the code is working too fast and is unable to delete the item before it can be saved again?

To test this, put a sleep in your code like this:

`System.IO.File.Delete(path);
Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
excelfile.SaveAs(path);`

If this works then it's recommended that you swap away from the sleep function as it causes the application to freeze whilst it is sleeping.

Edit: I realised the last part may be unclear: switch from the `Theading.Thread.Sleep(Time in ms)` to something like a hidden timer.

Comment: Still got the same issue